# How can I get data from a Toast notification when my app is opened by tapping the Toast notification?

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, toast

If a user clicks a Toast notification to open my app, is it possible to

- know the app was opened from a Toast notification?
- identify data from the Toast notification?

If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As outlined here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868212.aspx

Create toast so that it has `launch` parameters:

```
((XmlElement)toastNode).SetAttribute("launch", "{\"type\":\"toast\",\"param1\":\"12345\",\"param2\":\"67890\"}");
```

The toast XML will appear as

```
<toast launch="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;toast&quot;:&quot;param1&quot;:&quot;12345&quot;:&quot;param2&quot;:&quot;67890&quot;}">                        
    <visual>
        <binding template="ToastImageAndText01">
            <image id="1" src="ms-appx:///images/redWide.png" alt="red graphic"/>
            <text id="1">Hello World!</text>
        </binding>
    </visual>
</toast>
```

then in the app's `OnLaunched` method:

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    string launchString = args.Arguments

    ....
}
```